Imitate request from Postman with RestTemplate fails
I'm trying to consume a json from https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red. The request with postman works perfectly:

But when I try with Spring's RestTemplate as follows (trying to copy the request headers exactly):
final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

headers.set(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "PostmanRuntime/7.42.0");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.HOST, "ws-public.interpol.int");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*/*");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate, br");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION, "keep-alive");

final HttpEntity<Void> entity = new HttpEntity<>((Void) null, headers);

final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
    .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
    .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000L))
    .build();

final String response = restTemplate
    .exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class)
    .getBody();

my request fails with 403 Forbidden:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: "<HTML><HEAD><LF><TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE><LF></HEAD><BODY><LF><H1>Access Denied</H1><LF> <LF>You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;ws&#45;public&#46;interpol&#46;int&#47;" on this server.<P><LF>Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;1cf95568&#46;1730991641&#46;2abc645d<LF><P>https&#58;&#47;&#47;errors&#46;edgesuite&#46;net&#47;18&#46;1cf95568&#46;1730991641&#46;2abc645d</P><LF></BODY><LF></HTML><LF>"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at com.company.sample.MySampleApp.main(MySampleApp.java:55)

How can I successfully imitate the request by Postman? What am I missing?

Possibly what's under the authorization tab of postman? A 401 or a 403 is a generic "you're not allowed to do this" response, so if Postman is allowed but Spring Boot is not... there must be a difference in authentication/authorization on the request. Or the URL is wrong.

Nothing, it is empty. You can just click on the URL and open it through your browser as well. No authentication required.

Looks like Interceptor is the problem. Try without it. If works, fix the Interceptor.
Try the solution I suggested.

I'm sorry, that was a typo. No interceptor present, fixed the question.

Cool. try the solution I suggest.

Your solution is exactly the same to what I do, thank you anyways.

Nasty problem, there should be no functional difference in how an empty header is treated versus the header not being present at all. Wonky API implementation. But I guess somewhere in the Postman logging it should have logged the exact headers it sent, and there should be an empty cookie header listed there then. If all else fails, you could use a tool like Wireshark to sniff data being sent and received.

Edit:
Upon further investigation, it seems it just wants the Cookie header to work in general so here is the new working example:
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate, br")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "")
                .build();

        final String response = restTemplate
                .getForObject("https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red", String.class);


That's it, thanks!

Try this
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().setConnectTimeout(
    Duration.ofMillis(5000L)).setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000L)).build();

final String response = restTemplate.exchange("https://ws-public.interpol.int/notices/v1/red",
    HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();

